# Does wpa_supplicant allow using all characters and symbols in SSID?

Tags: wifi, ssid, wpa-supplicant

I've been researching the internet to understand what characters/symbols are allowed in a 32-byte/octet SSID. From the standard (https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/9363693) I understand that there is no restriction on types of characters, any character can be used as first/last etc.

When I run the **wpa_cli** program, though, I cannot set non-ASCII letters as an SSID.

Also, I set the name of my HotSpot to include foreign characters. I see the network in the **scan_results**, but the wpa_supplicant FAILs to connect to the HotSpot network. (With a regular ABCxyz name, it connects OK).

There are many companies that have restrictions on the characters allowed in the SSID. Does **wpa_supplicant** have such restrictions?

Answer (score 0):

`wpa_supplicant.conf` allows all octets, without restriction, if you enter the octets as hexadecimal. Taking examples from the [example configuration file](https://w1.fi/cgit/hostap/plain/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf), the usual case is that the SSID is a quoted ASCII string:

```
# Simple case: WPA-PSK, PSK as an ASCII passphrase, allow all valid ciphers
network={
    ssid="simple"
    psk="very secret passphrase"
    priority=5
}
```

But if your SSID or PSK does not fit the usual case, you can give them as hex:

```
# Special characters in SSID, so use hex string. Default to WPA-PSK, WPA-EAP
# and all valid ciphers.
network={
    ssid=00010203
    psk=000102030405060708090a0b0c0d0e0f101112131415161718191a1b1c1d1e1f
}
```

It seems that [the same approach should work with wpa_cli](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/624774/94707).